# MQTT with OLED realy :- display not coming properly

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

I am very new to Arduino/ESP and I am writing a code to activate 2 relays using MQTT. Also like to display status on OLED

here is my code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "SSD1306Wire.h"
#define wifi_ssid "ssid"
#define wifi_password "wifipassword"
#define mqtt_server "192.168.1.1"
#define mqtt_user "username"
#define mqtt_password "password"

SSD1306Wire  display(0x3c, D2, D1); 
const int relay1 = 5;
const int relay2 = 4;
String header;
String display_line2;
String output5State = "off";
String output4State = "off";
const int output5 = 5;
const int output4 = 4;

WiFiClient wificlient;
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

//------------------- MAIN WEB PAGE ------------------------
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>HOME IOT</title>
<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}
.button { background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px
text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer
body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;
.button2 {background-color: #77878A;
p {font-size: 24px;color: #444444;margin-bottom: 10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="webpage">
<h1>Security Door</h1>
<p><a href="/show/SecurityDoor/Open"><button class="button">Open</button></a></p>
<p><a href="/show/SecurityDoor/Close"><button class="button">Close</button></a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
)=====";
//------------------- MAIN WEB PAGE ------------------------

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //dht.begin();
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  //-----------------------------------------
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();
  wifiManager.autoConnect("IOT-LivinRoom");
  //-----------------------------------------
  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Initializing OLED Display");
  display.init();

  display.flipScreenVertically();
  display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_10);
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
  WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  String messageTemp;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)payload[i];
  }
  Serial.println();


 if(strcmp(topic, "livingroom/securitydoor") == 0){
     Serial.print("Changing esp01 relay1 to ");
     if(messageTemp == "on"){
       digitalWrite(relay1, LOW);
       Serial.print("On");
       doorOpening();

     }
     else if(messageTemp == "off"){
       digitalWrite(relay1, HIGH);
       Serial.print("Off");
       doorClosing();
     }
 }
 Serial.println();

 if(topic=="livingroom/ac"){
     Serial.print("Changing esp01 relay2 to ");
     if(messageTemp == "on"){
       digitalWrite(relay2, LOW);
       Serial.print("On");
       doorOpening();


     }
     else if(messageTemp == "off"){
       digitalWrite(relay2, HIGH);
       Serial.print("Off");
       doorClosing();
     } 
 }
 Serial.println();
}

void reconnect() {
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", mqtt_user, mqtt_password)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      client.subscribe("livingroom/securitydoor");
      client.subscribe("livingroom/ac");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

//--------------------------- void loop----------------------- 
void loop() {

  server.handleClient();
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

}

//----------------------------- Web Calls Function --------------------------------------
void handle_OnConnect() {
String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
server.send(200, "text/html", s);
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

//----------------------- LED display--------------------------------------

void doorOpening() {
  display.clear();
    display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
    display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
    display.drawString(0, 0, "Door");
    display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
    display.drawString(0, 28, "Opening");
  display.display();
}

void doorClosing() {
  display.clear();
    display.setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGN_LEFT);
    display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
    display.drawString(0, 0, "Door");
    display.setFont(ArialMT_Plain_24);
    display.drawString(0, 28, "Closing");
  display.display();
}
```

actually doorOpening() function is coming and doorClosing() function is not coming on OLED

again i am not very good in programming and arduino/esp8266

Comment: I would suggest leaving the MQTT broker and perhaps the OLED out of the software until you get the primary feature of opening and closing the garage door working as expected.  Also, there is no reason to assume certain libraries are compatible with one another.  Even if they work on one Arduino platform they may not work with one another on a different platform.

Comment: but here if i call the function in voild loop, oled is displaying what i expected also MQTT is always working for me.

i thought of doing the mqtt and oled before actual electrical circuit

Comment: Could be  a number if issues you might have with your code or the MQTT source.  For instance, are you actually sending "OFF" instead of "off" or even "Off"?  That is why I said do the simple things first.  Make sure they work.  Then add to what you know works.  When something breaks and you can not figure it out.  That would be the time to ask a question.

Comment: BTW, consider using Tasmota and a supported Sonoff ESP based product instead of writing your own code.  With Tasmota you can assume the MQTT feature works, the web server works, the WIFI works and the control over the supported Sonoff relays work.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue, actually relay pin was defined on D1 & D2 by mistake i connected oled to that pins